# Does CyanogenMod Xperia Z3 Dual support LTE on any SIMs?

Tags: 4g

Wiki does not really say word about that: https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Z3dual_Info

Stock image does support it.

If it doesn't, then what is current progress in context of dual sim?

Answer (score 1):

Always try to look at the specs directly from the manufacturer.  [Sony says LTE is supported](http://www.sonymobile.com/global-en/products/phones/xperia-z3-dual/specifications/) on some variants of the device.  CyanogenMod doesn't really have anything to do with it, since the radio code is not usually open-source and is not bundled with CM.

[GSM Arena](http://www.gsmarena.com/) is another good place to get device specs.